# Angular Server Side Rendering for each Routes

Tags: angular6, angular-universal

Once the angular universal is loaded, it switches to client side rendering. Subsequently, all the routes are rendered from the client. Is there a workaround, where I can render all the routes from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Create two new angular modules, one for browser and other for server, which will import 'App Module' generated by 'Angular CLI'.
U can detailed example on server side rendering for routes here, please refer: 
https://itnext.io/server-side-rendering-ssr-in-angular-5-the-simplest-and-quickest-ssr-approach-34cf53224f32